# Error running tensorflow test_streaming_accuracy.cc

Tags: tensorflow, command-line, speech-recognition, bazel

to run `test_streaming_accuracy.cc` , I ran the following command:

```
bazel run tensorflow/examples/speech_commands:test_streaming_accuracy --graph=/home/sweta/AudioRecognition/speech_commands_train/my_frozen_graph.pb --labels=/home/sweta/AudioRecognition/speech_commands_train/conv_labels.txt --wav=/home/sweta/AudioRecognition/speech_dataset/streaming_test_labels.wav --ground_truth=/home/sweta/AudioRecognition/speech_dataset/streaming_test_labels.txt --verbose
```

After executing this, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Unrecognized option: --graph=/home/sweta/AudioRecognition/speech_commands_train/my_frozen_graph.pb
```

**Anyone has any idea how to go about it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass arguments to the binary under `bazel run`, you'll need to include an additional `--` before your args, or else Bazel will parse those as arguments for itself.

e.g. `bazel run //my/binary:target --verbose_failures -- --arg_for_binary_target=42`

Comment: Yes I missed `--` . It is working after using `--`. Thank You @Jin